# Use a custom created Mapbox style (from Mapbox Studio) along with Leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, mapbox

I can't find any examples for how to use custom created Mapbox map-styles.

On the Mapbox page I created a style for a map.

How can I use this style with Leaflet?

For example:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [43.64701, -79.39425],
    zoom: 15
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);
```

Where do I put `mapbox://styles/ficht/cihqdfw3f004ybnm35e7zefon`?

This is the map:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/ficht/cihqdfw3f004ybnm35e7zefon.html?title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmljaHQiLCJhIjoiY2locWQ3YTBtMDAxYnY1bHVvcGtsM2Y1MCJ9.C8NlGmZuX6W2YrvXTHULeQ#1.6044619216776894/37.74890243399017/28.62971087861783/0.08751522544480395

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I successfully added a mapbox style to leaflet

On this URL https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/ select your style. Ill use a default style for this example (i think this one is available to all)
https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/mapbox/streets-v10/share/

Then on this page select the leaflet tab[image]

Copy the Url and use like so in your js file

```
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFza290YSIsImEiOiJjaXp0bmI3M3EwMDBvMndzMHJudnlsMDllIn0.jV7rTNmfiqjx57usCu54rQ', {
maxZoom: 18,
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
'<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Exactly what I needed, and what the OP needed also. I think this should be the accepted answer...

Comment: I think this has changed. I had to go to `use` and use the URL for `Fulcrum`

Comment: You can add a Mapbox Studio style to a Leaflet map using this endpoint with the L.TileLayer class:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_STYLE_ID/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN

Answer (score 33):

with current Mapbox version:

1. after you created your own style, click "Share..." at right top menu
2. You get popup, select Develop "Third Party" and in dropdown "CARTO"
3. copy "Integration URL". This is the link you need for Leaflet.js to set value for the 'tileLayer' object

[image: Where to find Leaflet-link for Custom Mapbox style]

Comment: Thanks! Only using this way can successfully print the map.

Answer (score 9):

It's really simple.

The URL to use your map as a tile map:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/YOUR_USERNAME/YOUR_STYLE_ID/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If you want to copy/import a style to your studio account:

```
https://www.mapbox.com/studio/styles/add-style/THE_USERNAME/THE_STYLE_ID/
```

Comment: can you expand on this answer, it seems really important! If you have hundreds of tiles, you can't click to create a studio style for each. Plus there is a 15 source limit per style. Do you add them to a 'new' style using the API and then use that link?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
let map = L.map('map',{
            center: [45.5017, -73.5673],
            zoom: 10
        })

L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18
        }).addTo(map)
```

Answer (score -8):

That won't work in combination with Leaflet, you'll need to switch to Mapbox GL:

- https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/
- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js

Example:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = YOUR_KEY;
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: YOUR_STYLE_URL
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});
```

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-style-id/

Comment: Actually they say you could use mapbox on their site http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html 

Anyway your example does what i need so thank you very much for the help!

Comment: you are mistaken, mapbox style does work with leaflet.

Comment: Well if so @RichardZilahi, then it would be nice if you include a 2015 reference link so people can see what you mean.